# How do I get rsync to email success/failure log on FreeBSD/FreeNAS 8.3?

Tags: rsync, freebsd, freenas

I've got a successful rsync local backup using:

```
rsync -vart --del /mnt/main/main /mnt/backup --log-file=/var/log/rsync_mainBackup.log
```

Can anyone tell me how the success/failure of the operation can be emailed to me?  Or even the .log file?

Answer (score 0):

you can check the return value of the rsync process and you can test for the existence of a maillog.

You can use the mail(1) command to send mail from the shell.